# how to upload a file from database without user interface in php

Tags: php, ajax

Help!!!
i want to upload a file from database(or from local m/c) to server in php without user interface. Is it possible.
Please Suggest.

Comment: What environment and database type? Mysql? Does the file reside in the database? What kind of file is it? etc.

Comment: Question needs to be a lot clearer. We have no idea what you are really asking... Of course it is possible, but we can;t help you if you don't expand.

Comment: How does the file get into the database without a UI?  Also, what database version are you using?

Comment: i am using mysql database in windows environment, file type is pdf. i want to automate this process.my main aim is to upload a file without user interaction

Comment: is this a server side or a client side app? you will be hard pressed to get a file upload to a remote server from a client machine with no user interaction... it's unsafe!

Comment: It is a webservice? What is? That thing you upload to? That is pretty much irrelevant. What counts is the thing that is sending the uploaded data.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention Ajax I assume you mean you want to upload it using JavaScript running in a web browser (and the server side component happens to use PHP).

This is impossible in the normal browser security context.

Users must explicitly select files to upload (otherwise webpages could go around stealing all sorts of private files behind users backs).

Users cannot do this without a user interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) from the command line:

```
curl --upload-file your.file.txt http://example.com/upload.php
```

Comment: @Darin can u tell me this in brief,please

Comment: You download and install `curl` from the address I provided and issue the previous command from the command prompt. It will POST the specified file to the given web address which could insert it into a database.